# What is the different between "put the computer to sleep" and "sleep after" in Windows 7?

Tags: windows

If you go to power setting in Windows 7, there are
"put the computer to sleep"

and in "advanced settings"
there is "sleep after"

Both let user choose a time period like 10 minutes, what is the different?

Answer (score 1):

These are the same setting. The first one just shows up in the basic customization page for the power plan, along with display-off time so these can be changed quickly, while the second one shows up in the advanced settings with detailed settings for many power options.

Comment: Look like they are different. You can have two different values and they would not update each other.

Comment: No, I just tried this and it shows the same setting in both places after changing. Ensure that the same power plan is selected in the Advanced Settings pane.